# Haskell print integer matrix in ghci

Tags: haskell, matrix

I want to print 4x4 matrix of integers which were formed by my function f.

```
import Numeric
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data
--import Numeric.Matrix
import Data.Array

f m n | (n==0) = 0
f m n | (m==1) = n
f m n   = f (m-1) n + f m (n-1)  

mymat = matrix 4 4 $ f
```

On the last line the type error, and I want find proper variant of function that fills the 2d matrix with results of calculation of function of row and column.

======Edited======

I have found the solution, but it is strange that it's not easy to find a standart function of matrix filling. Maybe there is one?

```
import Numeric
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data
import Data.Array

f m n | (n==0) = 1
f m n | (m==0) = 1   
f m n   = f (m-1) n + f m (n-1)  

qw x y 0 = [f 0 0]
qw x y n = (qw x y (n-1))  ++ [f (mod n x) (div n y) ]

mymat x y = matrix x (qw x y (x*y-1))
```

Comment: Always add the exact error message.

Comment: Your function `f` does not create a matrix in a way that the `matrix` functions accepts. It takes a number of rows and a flat list containing the contents. `f` is simply a function of type `Int -> Int -> Int`. You can turn it into a nested list for use with `matrix` with eg. `[ f x y | x <- [0..3], y <- [0..3] ]`.

Comment: Always add the exact error message, always use type signatures, and always make sure the code you post actually reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all commentators.
Question now is not actual because I was looking for this piece of code:

```
matrix 4 [ f x y | x <- [0..3], y <- [0..3] ]
```